# How can OS X be installed from ISO file on a Mac?

Tags: macos, startup, install, iso

How can OS X be installed from an ISO file on a Mac?

I have downloaded OS X Mountain Lion ISO file (4.42GB) as my MacBook fails to boot and I want to do a fresh installation.

Comment: Please don't pirate OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Restore the ISO using Disk Utility to a disk partition (internal or external) then boot from that (hold ⌥ on boot).